# How to start/stop marquee on enter key press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

following is the code snippet for marquee to stop on mouse click down and start on mouse click up. I need to change it to detect the event of pressing enter key from keyboard. How is that possible? thanks

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmousedown="this.stop();" onmouseup="this.start();">
Go on... click me (and hold the mouse down)!
</marquee>
```

Comment: [JavaScript | Trigger a button on ENTER key](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-trigger-a-button-on-enter-key) Have a look at this GeeksForGeeks article, that should help

Comment: Just as a note: [`<marquee>` tag is considered deprecated and obsolete!](https://html.com/tags/marquee/#The_Marquee_Element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <body>
         <marquee id="marquee" behavior="scroll" direction="left" 
          onmousedown="this.stop();" onmouseup="this.start();">
          Go on... click me (and hold the mouse down)!
          </marquee>
          <script>
                 if(document.readyState){
                     const marquee = document.getElementById('marquee');
                     document.body.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
                     if(event.key == 'Enter'){
                          marquee.stop()
                     }
                 })
                     document.body.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
                         if(event.key == 'Enter'){
                     marquee.start()
        }
    })
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```